# Calculating the inverse Fourier transform of two given functions

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of the following functions:

1. $\displaystyle f(w) = e^{(-\pmb{i}5w)} * {\rm sinc}(2w) $
2. $\displaystyle g(w) = \frac{\pmb{i}w}{(3+\pmb{i}w)(1+\pmb{i}w)} $

I'm really stuck and I don't know where to start, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this homework?  Are you having trouble evaluating the integrals,  or setting them up?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The second question can be solved by staring at it and then using the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). Do you know that? For the first question: maybe you know which function gives the sinc function when Fourier transformed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are some hints:**

1) If $e_t(x)= e^{itx}$,what is $\widehat{e_tf}$?

2) What is $\widehat{f'}$?

---

Also note that it is important to state the exact definition of the Fourier transform if you wish to compute explicit functions.

---